# Decimal/double to integer - round up (not just to nearest)

Tags: c#, numbers

How would you **round up** a decimal or float to an integer. For instance...

```
0.0 => 0
0.1 => 1
1.1 => 2
1.7 => 2
2.1 => 3
```

Etc.

Comment: What behaviour do you want for negative numbers? does -1.1 go to -1 (go to larger) or -2 (go to farther from zero)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Simple, use [`Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cz5da1c.aspx):

```
var wholeNumber = (int)Math.Ceiling(fractionalNumber);
```

Comment: I know it's off-topic, but may I ask you why you used `var` and not `int`?

Comment: Purely out of habit. `var` can be useful when declaring objects of a longer type like `var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>()` for example.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
int myInt = (int)Math.Ceiling(myDecimal);
```

Comment: Why convert to a string only to parse back? Just cast it.

Answer (score 1):

Before saying it does not work, you have to check that ALL VALUES in the operation are double type. 
Here is an example in C#:

```
 int speed= Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)distance/ (double)time));
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.Ceiling not working for me, I use this code and this work :)

```
int MyRoundedNumber= (int) MyDecimalNumber;
                if (Convert.ToInt32(MyDecimalNumber.ToString().Split('.')[1]) != 0)
                    MyRoundedNumber++;
```

and if you want to round negative number to down for example round -1.1 to -2 use this

```
  int MyRoundedNumber= (int) MyDecimalNumber;
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(MyDecimalNumber.ToString().Split('.')[1]) != 0)
                        if(MyRoundedNumber>=0)
                           MyRoundedNumber++;
                        else
                           MyRoundedNumber--;
```

Comment: This is a horrible approach. Convert to string, seriously?

Answer (score -1):

```
var d = 1.5m;
var i = (int)Math.Ceiling(d);
Console.Write(i);
```

Comment: This just *rounds* the number, it doesn't necessarily round it **up**.