# How to round up decimal value to the nearest whole number?

Tags: c#

I need to round up value like 0.15, 0.20, 0.25 to nearest whole number 1. I'm trying like below but it is returning 0.

```
decimal fees = Math.Round(30 * 0.005M);
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion on the above.

Comment: Round up is `Math.Ceiling` instead of `.Round`

Comment: thank you it's working now.

Comment: Math.Round(30 * 0.005M, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

Comment: This is a basic c# feature, why all these people are answering an obvious duplicate is beyond me. -edit- Why people are upvoting these is even more beyond me... want quality? Don't upvote dupe answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Math.Ceiling`

```
decimal fees = Math.Ceiling(30 * 0.005M);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 decimal fees = Math.ceil(30 * 0.005M);
```

Comment: Don't answer duplicates

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at Math.Ceiling. Also you should search your query before asking a question and you would have found:

[Decimal/double to integer - round up (not just to nearest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666069/decimal-double-to-integer-round-up-not-just-to-nearest)

Comment: Don't answer duplicates